# EditText that looks like TextView inside a ListView

Tags: android, textview, android-listview, android-edittext, inline-editing

I am [developing an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000630/is-this-is-ok-to-use-the-listview-for-inline-editing) where the user can edit the data in the `ListView`. I want to have an `EditText` inside that ListView, this edittext should behave like TextView but when the user clicks it it should look like `EditText`, How can i achieve this functionality?

Actually the EditText inside the ListView looks ugly & i want that the EditText should look like a TextView bydefault but when the user try to Edit the data then it should look like the EditText.

I hope that my question is clear if not please ask.

Comment: Check my app screenshots, are you looking for this type of output ?

Comment: EditText Et; // initialize your edittext//

Et.setCursorVisible(false);
Et.setLongClickable(false);
Et.setClickable(false);
Et.setFocusable(false);
Et.setSelected(false);
Et.setKeyListener(null);
Et.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);

And you'll never see it like an EditText again.

(Answering a question by typing on a phone is such a pain. Moderators, please reformat the answer.)Just in case you want to do it without XMLs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below files I used in my app.

**main.xml** in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00f"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" />    
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00f"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**myshape.xml** in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">   
    <solid   android:color="#fff"/> 
    <corners android:radius="2dip" />   
    <stroke android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#ff4500" />
</shape>
```

**bg.xml** in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <item android:state_enabled="true"        
        android:state_focused="true"                        
        android:drawable="@drawable/myshape"/>    
</selector>
```

**Java file**

```
public class EditTextSelector extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **selector** for EditText to create different states. If it is in idle state give normal color drawable as background and if it is focussed use a 9 patch PNG drawable which resembles real EditText background.

I hope it may help you. If you don't know how to use selector, feel free to ask me.

**Sample ScreenShots**

I am using 1 TextVuew and 2 EditText views in my app, check below screen shots to know how 
the EditText will look like according to your requirements. If you like them and it is actually required then i post code here.

**Initial Screen**

[image]

**While taking Input for 1st EditText**

[image]

**While taking Input for 2nd EditText**

[image]

Comment: I am very new to the android, if you can guide me how to do it? it will be so nice of you.

Comment: wait i will post code in new answer. The code for app with above screen shots only.

Answer (score 0):

well, I would recommend to use textview.. and when click on it it will swap to editText(add View /removeView ) in parent.. and when focus changes it will reverted back to textview with new changes .. second solution to use popup dialog for editing purpose with done button to submit and back to get back to list. third solution to change style of editText with :

```
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.writemode);
//later after this item loses focus, use:
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.readmode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setCursorVisible(false) to hide the cursor and onclick of edittext setCursorVisible(true). this, also set background color to white of edittext

Answer (score 0):

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can prompt user To input with an AlertDialog.