# How to move the text back to its old position after changing the background of editText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have a an editText whose background I have set to transparent to make it look like a textView.[image: initial editText]

On the Onfocuschanged method, when in focus I set the background resource as

```
ph.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
```

[image: after focus]

And when focus is removed I want to make it look like a textView again, so I set the background as

```
 ph.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[image: moved text]

But the text in the editText stays in the position of the previous background and does not return to its original position.

EDIT:
Added xml code for the editText

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/ph"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />
```

Comment: How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved this problem by using

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView12"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
```

Baseline allignment actually alligns the 2 vies text to text. So when I change the background from transparent to 
android.R.drawable.edit_text it alligns itto the texView12 according to the position of the text not the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

`ph.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

with

`ph.setBackground(null);`

Edit:

add the following lines after setting the background to transparent.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, R.id.textView12);
ph.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: try once more with `setBackground(null)`. If it does not work, please add your xml layout to your original post.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, its not working. I have added the xml code.

Comment: Any other suggestion plz?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this dint work but it gave me the idea how to solve this! I have added the answer.

Comment: Also anyone wants to try the above, then use ALIGN_LAYOUT_BOTTOM, not ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.

Comment: I am sorry, I have made a typo there, but yes, your solution is correct, you have align the baseline instead of bottom

Answer (score 0):

After you sets ph.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text); you change an img src field of EditText. 
Try manipulate only with Drawable. 
Change 
 `ph.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text)`

to

```
ph.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.edit_text));
```

and then replace

ph.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

with

ph.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

Comment: Ok. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017903/edittext-that-looks-like-textview-inside-a-listview

Comment: Ya I saw it, I guess this will be my fallback if I cant figure out the above one.