# I can't write into the EditText, it disappears when i try to write something, its because the getView() is called when i modify the data

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, inline-editing

**EDIT:**

> I found the reason which is that the getView() is called when i try to
>   edit something, so the data from the DataAdapter is loaded & my edited
>   changes disappears.

**EDIT:**

> i observed one thing, if there are few rows in the listview then its
>   OK, but if there are many rows which the listview can not show in the
>   visible screen (Scroll bar appears to scroll to other records), then
>   the issue arises!!

I am working on project where we have implemented an [INLINE EDITING using ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000630/is-this-is-ok-to-use-the-listview-for-inline-editing), i.e. the data can be edited inside the listview.

I have a defined an xml for each item/row of that ListView. I am using Custom DataAdapter to bind the data with ListView.

When i first time load that activity the ListView is loaded, i can edit the data & it works fine. When something is edited the changes are saved to the SQLite database, i have a button for this purpose.

Now the issue is that after the data is saved FOR THE VERY FIRST TIME & the listview is loaded again, i can not edit the data anymore. When i try to edit the data the keyboard appears & then disappears automatically & the ENTERED DATA also disappears. Please see the screen shots.

**Can some one help me to resolve this issue?**

my Custom Adapter class:

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuestionEntity> {
      private ArrayList<QuestionEntity> items;
      private Context CurrentContext;
      private QuestionEntity CurrentItem;
      private Cursor    OptionsCursor;


    public QuestionAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<QuestionEntity> items, Cursor curOptions) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.grid_item, items);
        this.CurrentContext = context;
        this.items          = items;
        this.OptionsCursor  = curOptions;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        //verify that the items list is still valid since
        //the list may have been cleared during an update
        if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
                return convertView; //Can't extract item

        CurrentItem = items.get(position);    

        if(convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(CurrentContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }

        if (convertView != null) 
        {

            TextView txtQuestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
            txtQuestion.setText(CurrentItem.getTitle());

            Spinner cmbOptions = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmbOptions);

            /*
             * Load the options from OptionsCursor
             */

            LoadOptions(cmbOptions);

            /*
             * Attach onItemClick event with cmbOptions 
             * When the user change the option we will populate the comments based on the option
             */

            cmbOptions.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
            {
                try
                {
                    //If MyCondition is true show msg to user.

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.toString();
                }

            }
            });

        }
        return convertView;

    }

    private void LoadOptions(Spinner iacOptions)
    {
        //Load data in the spinner using the OptionsCursor

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to revise your code and see if [`Adapter.getView(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method is called when it shouldn't. This could happen because of redundant call of [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Just add logging to these methods and see if they are called at the right place and time.

Comment: According to your question update it becomes quite obvious that the problem is in your implementation of `Adapter.getView(..)`. You refresh the view with the stored data while its being edited. You should check in this method if the `EditText` is being typed into at the moment of `Adapter.getView(..)` call and if so then not to refresh it.

Comment: You are the correct the issue is that the Adapter.getView() is called when i try to modify the data. Can you help me to resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: Post your code then. The implementation of `Adapter` and the code where `notifyDataSetChanged()` (or `notifyDataSetInvalidated()`) is called are of particular interest.