# Editable List/Grid

Tags: android, android-listview, grid, ormlite

I have a number of objects which are fairly simple data style classes with many attributes with getters and setters for each attribute... an example might be along the lines of:

```
private employee ()
{
   private String firstName();
    private String secondName();
    private boolean disabled();
    private int yearsInService();

    //various Getters and Setters
    public String getFirstName();
    public void setFirstName(String name);

    public boolean getDisabled();        
    public void setDisabled(boolean value);        
}
```

These classes are populated via OrmLite/SQLIte 
Some of these classes have 30 or 40 attributes.
My intention is to display these attributes in a grid/list of some kind to the user - ideally something with a description column and a value column, and that the user be able to select any particular attribute modify the value.  Possibly like the Preferences screen only these aren't preferences?

I've done a fair amount of searching and I'm not really getting a feel for the best solution at the moment.  Should I be using Listview?  It seems complex to get something like this set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [ListView OR Grid for INLINE Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000630/is-this-is-ok-to-use-the-listview-for-inline-editing) you may experience certain [issues like discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081700/i-cant-write-into-the-edittext-it-disappears-when-i-try-to-write-something-it).

> So the best option is to populate the data in a ListView & when the
>   user clicks to edit it, display a dialogue to them & provide the
>   EDITING functionality there.